# How can I declare type of an ES6 module in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a generic interface for a repository like this.

```
export interface IBaseRepository<T> {
    create(model: T): T;
    edit(model: T): T;
    read(): T
}
```

I'm trying to implement this repository interface in a functional module like this (since it's basically a stateless singleton).

```
// user-repository.ts
export function create(model: IUser): IUser { ...code }

export function edit(model: IUser): IUser { ...code }

export function read(): IUser { ...code }
```

Is there any way to ensure that `IBaseRepository` is implemented in `UserRepository`. Or do I have to always implement the repository as a class and export an instantiated singleton?

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Comment: @JaredSmith I probably shouldn't tag stuff I'm not completely sure of :/

Comment: Hovering the mouse cursor over the tag will bring up a tooltip with a description of what the tag is about to help you decide.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JaredSmith I'll definitely use that next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bundle all functions into an object and have that exported.

Something like this:

```js
import { IBaseRepository } from './master';
// user-repository.ts
export function create(model: string): string { return ''; }

export function edit(model: string): string { return ''; }

export function read(): string { return ''; }

export const repository: IBaseRepository<string> = { create, edit, read };
```

And use it like you would use anything else that module exports:

```js
import { repository } from './repo';

repository.create('test');
```

Or use the **export default** to export the functions directly if you want to have that type for the default module export.

```js
import { IBaseRepository } from './master';
// user-repository.ts
export function create(model: string): string { return ''; }

export function edit(model: string): string { return ''; }

export function read(): string { return ''; }

export default { create, edit, read } as IBaseRepository<string>;
```

And import the module to get it or import the functions separately :

```js
import repo, { create } from './repo';

repo.create('test');
```

You can still import each function independently of course.

**Note** use types according to your example I just tried to keep things simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I ended up using the `export default` option as that seems to represent the interface of the repository more closely. And the code looks so much cleaner now!

I just wish there was a better way to define the public interface (exports) of a module and strictly constraint the implementation in Typescript.

Comment: you could do easily do that if you were to group your functions in a class that implements that interface (as you would in any other OOP language). But since you insist in having the operations separate there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
interface IFoo {
    foo(): boolean;
    bar();
}

namespace Foo {
    export function foo() {
        return 42;
     }
}

declare type assert<T, K extends T> = {};
declare const check1: assert<IFoo, typeof Foo>;
```

We get a nice error on the check1:

```
Type 'typeof Foo' does not satisfy the constraint 'IFoo'.
  Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
    Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

My example has an inline module, but it should be similar to assert an external module using a `import * as Foo from './foo';`

Comment: I just tried out your method, It feels a bit verbose having to use assert explicitly for all namespace declarations. But this is a very unique take on the problem and it does seem to solve the issue of  defining strict module interface declarations head on.